# Polymer Access node_modules outside of app root

Tags: node.js, polymer

I am developing a polymer website and an node.js server. I use the following folder structure:

[Folder Structure Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IthLN.png)

I need to access a element from node_modules inside the polymer app, but I can't access the node_modules folder, because it is one layer above my app root.

My question is how to configure the polymer app to be able to access the node_modules folder from the polymer app with the given project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer can only answer what is publicly served by your server, so you need to update your server to serve node_modules or include the code inside your elements and bundle them together.